# Uploading files in a free host server

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to automatically transfer files in a new folder in my site directory I use this code:

```
$errors = array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {

    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

if($file_size > 2097152) {

    $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';

}

$connexion -> exec("INSERT INTO user_details (USER_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE, NOM, PRENOM, choix) VALUES ('', '$file_name', '$file_size', '$file_type', '$NOM', '$PRENOM', '$choix';
```

And received this error message:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/disk5/2035382/www/olexim.co.nf/traitement.php on line 30
```

Comment: `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']` is not an array. And please don't attach a screenshot of your code, post your code here.

Comment: okay i'm a new user in this site .. files is an array : <input type="file" name="files[]" value="Parcourir des fichiers" multiple/> .. the code work in localhost but in biz.co i receive this error

Comment: Post your full HTML code.

Comment: @KhaledClaudeBoussoffara It's difficult to see how you're processing the files. Please update the question with your php code. Or, you can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34311341/5517143).

Comment: <form action="traitement.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Form:</legend>
.....
   
   <input type="file" name="files[]" value="Parcourir des fichiers" multiple/><br><hr>
   
 </form>

Comment: $errors= array();
     foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
      {
          $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
          $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
          $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key]; 
          if($file_size > 2097152) .....

Comment: Remove the `['tmp_name']` part and it should work.